# Consume google custom search json apis on iOS app

Tags: ios, google-custom-search

I am trying to fetch images from google and show them inside my app for which I am trying to consume custom search apis of google what I have done till now:

1. Create a custom search engine.
2. In the API list I have turned on Custom Search
3. API key for my app with its bundle identifier
4. GTL library, GTLService, NSURL connection

But every time I get the result:

```
"error": {"errors": [{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured",
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."}],"code": 403,"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." }}
```

Comment: Here is guide fro all you need to do to get it to work http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600

Answer (score 0):

To activate an API for your project, do the following:

1.)Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project.
In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth.
In the displayed list of available APIs, find the one you want to activate, and set its status to ON.

UPDATE: 
2.) Then go to "API Access" and specify your calling domains or IP addresses